# Como usar UpdateProgress com EnablePartialRendering=false?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp

Tenho uma página onde precisa preencher dois dropdownlist, mas não carrega o UpdateProgress caso o EnablePartialRendering esteja como false. Se estiver como true, o UpdateProgress é carregado, mas o segundo DDL não.

Comment: vamos por partes, seu `dropdrownlist` está dentro de um `if(!postback)` no load da página?

Comment: Já arrumei. Obrigado.